# Converting an Image or Text into a link to another page in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can I convert an image or text into a link to navigate to another page in the same project in C#? If so, please let me know. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. 
Regards.

Comment: Is your question about how to create pages? or how to make image as a link/

Comment: It was actually to navigate from one page to other using Image or text as a link and not a button

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make an image or a text field and do a click command on it?

Then in the click command open the corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

Wpf support [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx), which can be used for [navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) between pages
but I never use it, generally [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is best way to do that, you can find example project [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)